# Возникла сложность с register_activation_hook

Tags: wordpress

Смысл таков, что при активации плагина - добавляется пост в базу один раз и все. В моем коде он не добавляется, хотя die('ggg') срабатывает. У меня при подключении ab_add_test_cars() находится хук 'init', в WP-Kama написано:

```
register_activation_hook() не будет работать если его активировать в момент срабатывания хука plugins_loaded или init
```

Как мне быть в такой ситуации? 
my_plugin.php:

```
$ttt = 0;
require_once 'functions.php';
if($ttt == 0){
    register_activation_hook(__FILE__,'ab_add_test_cars');
$ttt = 1;
}
```

functions.php:

```
function ab_insert_cars(){
$post_data = array(
    'post_type' => 'cars',
    'post_title' => 'title_sss',
    'post_content' => 'trhnjtrnnr',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_author' => 1,
);
$post_id =wp_insert_post( $post_data);
function ab_add_test_cars() {
    add_action('init', 'ab_insert_cars');
    //die('gggg');
}
```

Comment: ` У меня при подключении ab_add_test_cars() находится хук 'init', с которым нельзя одновременно (WP-Kama)` - переведите с русского на русский, пожалуйста.

Comment: И вложенные функции в php - клиническое зло. Более того, смысла в них ноль. Зачем вы так сделали?

Comment: @KAGG Design, да, Вы правы, я что-то не так написал в описании вопроса, простите

Comment: @KAGG Design, попробую напрямую тогда подключить функцию ab_insert_cars

Comment: @KAGGDesign, на мой взгляд, это больше похоже не на вложенные функции, а на потерянную закрывающуюся скобку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В коде есть несколько ошибок существенных ошибок, даже не принимая во внимание дисбаланс фигурных скобок.

Во-первых, `require_once 'functions.php';` лишено всякого смысла. Потому что ваш код, который будет использовать functions.php, будет исполняться по событию init, а в этот момент уже все плагины, а также тема - загружены. Последовательность загрузки (очень упрощённо) примерно такая:

- загрузка плагинов
- загрузка темы
- срабатывание события init

Подробнее [здесь](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference).

Во-вторых, ссылка из плагина на тему выглядит странно. Обычно все посты кастомного типа, с которыми работает плагин, объявляют прямо в нём, по событию init. Ну да ладно, оставим это как замечание к стилистике кода.

А главное, что ваш хук по init предполагает, что тип поста `cars` уже объявлен. Но объявление этого типа поста в functions.php происходит ведь тоже по событию init. Нет гарантии, что хук из плагина будет вызван позже объявления поста.

Поэтому в вашей строке объявления хука надо указать приоритет. По умолчанию он 10. Можно поставить 20, чтобы ваша функция была вызвана позже.

```
add_action( 'init', 'ab_insert_cars', 20 );
```

Полный код в теле плагина должен выглядеть примерно так:

```
 /**
 * Plugin Name: My Cool Plugin
 * Plugin URI: 
 * Description: This is a plugin.
 * Author: 
 * Version: 1.0
 * Author URI: 
 * Requires at least: 4.4
 * Tested up to: 4.9
 *
 * Text Domain: 
 * Domain Path: /languages/
 */


if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}

static $plugin;

if ( ! isset ( $plugin ) ) {
    register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'ab_add_test_cars' );
    $plugin = true;
}

function ab_add_test_cars() {
    add_action( 'init', 'ab_insert_cars', 20 );
}
```

Возможно, есть ещё какие-то проблемы, но точнее сказать сложно, не видя кода целиком.